# Add Bean For Public Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a Spring Boot application and I am adding some code that I had made in a regular Spring MVC application (not Boot).

When I run it, I get an error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userService in app.WelcomeController required a bean of type 'com.myorg.account.service.UserService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myorg.account.service.UserService' in your configuration.
```

So I added Qualifier and Autowired to UserService. Full code below.

```
package com.myorg.account.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import com.myorg.account.model.User;

@Controller
@Configuration
public interface UserService {
     @Autowired(required = true)
     @Qualifier(value="UserService")
    @Bean
    void save(User user);

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Above WelcomeController I specify the qualifier which I thought would fix the issue.

```
@ComponentScan
@Controller
@Service("UserInterface")
public class WelcomeController {
```

Here is the userService field mentioned in the error. This is from WelcomeController.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this will work. I see multiple problems with your code. Look for a working example online that may give you an idea how to put things together.

Comment: Is there anything in particular you would point me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `@Controller` annotation not to the interface `UserService` but to class which implement `UserService` interface.

Delete all annotations from `UserService` and left only `@Controller` in 'WelcomeController'

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController implements UserService {
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your answer. I tried adding @Controller to UserServiceImplementation and the app is not running yet. Is there anything else I may need to do, like other annotations?

Comment: You need to do that I wrote in my answer and create new class with `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` for application configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. You made me very happy!